# Concatenation question. (One word to rule them all/most)

Tags: meaning, grammar, synonyms

Is there a word for the process of adding to or removing parts from a word (prefixes, suffixes and the like) to alter it's meaning? Like nounization, but for all types of words not just specific to verbs, adjectives or nouns.

**EDIT**

As clarification I would like to offer an example in another language. In Swahili - my native tongue, bear with me - they have the perfect word that I've never had used in any other context other than I described in my question "**Unyambulishaji**" so much so that the closest term in English to it is **Transmission** which doesn't do the word justice given the specificity of its meaning.

I'm not looking for a general word. Something closer to the tune of **Neologisms** and how it's applied rather than **Manipulate**. All neologisms are manipulations of a language and its sounds but not all manipulations are neologisms.

Comment: Affixation and stemming?

Comment: No, not really. English doesn't do much of that, and what there is is pretty irregular. Languages with more inflection, like Latin or Sanskrit, have many more terms because they have many more procedures like that, and they're pretty regular so names are useful. If you want to see what the terminology is for what English does have, see [the Inflection handout](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Inflection.pdf).

Answer (score -1):

"tweak" or "recast"

ref for 'tweak' - [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tweak)

ref for 'recast' - [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/recast)

Comment: Hi, and welcome to ELU. Please take the [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and consider how you might [improve your answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). As it stands, this sounds like opinion. Can you cite a reference to show this is a common use?

Comment: @Davo I beg your pardon for my obscure reply. I've updated the same with supporting ref links.

Comment: I get what you meant by your answer but that's not what I was looking for. I was looking for a word specific to the application of language not ones that can be used generally like "tweak" or "recast". Thanks for your contribution though.

Comment: @Mark I suppose, the word you are looking for is 'cohesive' with ref to [FutureLearn](https://www.futurelearn.com/courses/understanding-ielts-writing/4/steps/848734)

Comment: Your link isn't helping me out much @PBKN I created an account enrolled in the course but I still can't see what you're referring to cause I have to wait 33 days for the course to be available. Take a screenshot or something.

Comment: @Mark Sorry about that, I'll copy-paste the contents in it.
Cohesion refers to how you link ideas together, whether in the same sentence, between sentences or across paragraphs. This involves the use of what are called ‘cohesive devices’. These include linking words, reference words such as ‘this’, ‘that’, ‘the former’ etc. and substitutions, where you use synonyms to link back to earlier information.